# xfce-terminal new window at random location plus echo that value

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, terminal, xfce

I want to spawn new xfce-terminal windows and run some arbitrary code. I can get it to generate a random number and use that as the X coordinate for the window location, but I would like to also pass the value and have it (for example) print it in the new window.

So if I have:

```
TEST=$(( $RANDOM % 100 + 20 ))
xfce4-terminal --geometry 160x40+$TEST+40 -e 'bash -c "echo the number is $TEST; bash"'
```

It correctly creates the window at the random location, but the terminal output in the new window is "the number is " without the value attached.

Any insight appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Beside the point, but that internal `bash` opens an unnecessary subshell. You could do `exec bash` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes don't allow variable expansions. Use double quotes instead (which requires switching to single quotes on the inside).

```
... -e "bash -c 'echo the number is $TEST; bash'"
```